# Parse JSON body with escape characters with FLASK framework

Tags: python-2.7, rest, post, flask

I had built a REST Service ontop of the Flask framework. I have a route whith takes a POST request with the JSON body. Requests which will be consumed by that route will have escape characters (\" and \t). Request example:

```
curl -k -X POST "http://127.0.0.1:8000/some" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\t\"name\": \"Alex\",\t\"age\": \"21\"}
```

Can you please help me to figure out how to properly parse the JSON body with escape characters?

I have tried to extract JSON body with the method .json but I was getting an exception: *"400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand."*.

As far as I understand .json methode can parse body only without escape character like:

```
curl -k -X POST "http://127.0.0.1:8000/some" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{"name":"Alex","age": "21"}
```

My current code with the .json method.

```
from flask import Flask, request

@app.route('/some', methods=['POST'])
def raise_request():
    content = request.json
    name = content["name"]
    surname = content["surneme"]
    print name 
    print surname
    return "Hello {} {}".format(name, surname), 200
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `literal_eval` to handle the escape characters, then use `flask.json.loads` on that result.

```
from ast import literal_eval
from flask import json

@app.route('/some', methods=['POST'])
def raise_request():
    content = request.get_data(as_text=True)
    content = literal_eval("'%s'" % content)
    content = json.loads(content)
    name = content["name"]
    age = content["age"]
    return "Hello {} {}".format(name, age)
```